# need help display query in codeignitier view with condition ($Code)

Tags: codeigniter

for example i have database :

```
id  | Code | Name     |  Age |
==============================
1   | 111  | AAAA     |  21  |
2   | 121  | BBBB     |  23  |
```

and sql query code :

```
public function detail($Code)
    {
        $tSQL = "select * from table_employee where Code = '{$Code}' ";

        $query = $this->db->query($tSQL);

        return $query->num_rows();

    }
```

how to display in view

```
<?php 
if( !empty($detail) ) {                                                                     foreach($detail as $row) { ?>       
<?php echo "<tr>" ?>                                                        <?php echo "<td width='1%'><center>".$row->code;"<center></td>" ?>
<?php echo "<td width='1%'><center>".$row->name;"<center></td>"?>
<?php echo "<td width='1%'><center>".$row->age;"<center></td>"?>                            
<?php }} ?>
```

from condition where theres any one know?

Answer (score 0):

In view you only need to use  tag to your php syntax

```
 <?php 
    if(!empty($detail) ) {
     foreach($detail as $row) { ?>       
        <tr>
        <td width='1%'><center><?php echo $row->code;?> <center></td>
        <td width='1%'><center><?php echo $row->name;?> <center></td>
        <td width='1%'><center><?php echo $row->age;?><center></td> 
        </tr>                          
    <?php }} ?>
```

Comment: error say "message: Missing argument 1 for detailemployee_model::detail(),"

Comment: Please send you model and controller code as well , for better understanding.

Comment: this my controller :

Comment: You need to add this line in your function:

public function detail($Code)
    {
        $tSQL = "select * from table_employee where Code = '{$Code}' ";

        $query = $this->db->query($tSQL);
       $result = $query->result_array();
      $this->load->view('Your view page ', $result);
    }

Comment: this my controller :

<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Infoemployee extends CI_Controller {

 public function __construct()
 {
  parent::__construct();
  $this->load->database();
  $this->load->model('detailemployee_model','infoemployee');
 }

        public function index()
 {
           $data['detail'] = $this->infoemployee->detail();
           $this->load->view('detailemployee_view', $data);
           } 
  else redirect(base_url());
}}

Comment: $data['detail'] = $this->infoemployee->detail();

Probably you are not passing parameter $code here.

as defined in :

public function detail($Code)
    {
        $tSQL = "select * from table_employee where Code = '{$Code}' ";

        $query = $this->db->query($tSQL);

        return $query->num_rows();

    }

Comment: or maybe i have to add 
 
$data['detail'] = $this->infoemployee->detail($Kode);
but still say missing 1 argumen

Comment: Yes, $code value is missing , so this is showing missing argument error.

Answer (score 0):

Try once..

Controller..

```
public function detail($Code)
    {
        $this->db->where('Code',$Code);
        $data = $this->db->get('table_employee')->result();

        return $data;

    }
```

In view

```
foreach($data as $row) { ?>       
    <tr>
    <td width='1%'><center><?php echo $row->code;?> <center></td>
    <td width='1%'><center><?php echo $row->name;?> <center></td>
    <td width='1%'><center><?php echo $row->age;?><center></td> 
    </tr>                          
 <?php } ?>
```